# How to run a Rshiny applet without RStudio

Tags: java, r, applet

I have build a RShiny applet. 
Now, I would like friends being able to use it without having to install RStudio or deal with the code.

I was thinking of something similar to a Java applet which can be wrapped in a .jar-file and the customer being able to use it without needing the code.
Is this also possible for Rshiny applets?

Comment: just load your app on your server or on RStudio's server. look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson7/

Answer (score 2):

You might need R and the `shiny` package. You can go without `RStudio`.

Firstly write a small R file (named tmp.R) with the following lines:

```
library(shiny)
runApp("path to your shiny App")
```

Then in the command line. Type the following cmd.

```
R --vanilla <tmp.R &
```

Then your shiny App is running in your computer. Type the IP address (such as http://127.0.0.1:5713/) given by R in the web browser. There is your shiny App.